# How to unit test what is setup in overridden OnModelCreating

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and in my context I have overridden OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

Inside the method, I set up the database configuration. I would like to test what is set up. For instance, I have the following code:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
```

I would like to have a unit test which checks that HasDefaultSchema with parameter value "public" is called.

Or like in the following example I would like to test that HasMany and WithMany methods of entity UserGroup are called:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>()
             .HasMany<User>(g => g.Users)
             .WithMany(u => u.Groups)
             .Map(ug =>
                  {
                     ug.MapLeftKey("GroupId");
                     ug.MapRightKey("UserId");
                     ug.ToTable("UserGroupMembers");
                  });
```

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: May I ask why? It feels like you are testing implementation details and that the tests you are going to write are just copies of what you put in OnModelCreating? What's the value of testing this?

Comment: Not sure of Antipod's reasons, but for me, I ran into this scenario when I was trying to TDD a new application. I knew I had to set the default schema to a certain value, but I didn't know how to write the test to verify expected behaviour, without resorting to verifying that a certain method was called. I checked the API for `DBContext`, but couldn't find a way to view the configurations of the used model. If there was a way, that would be the preferred method over expected mock calls.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with the following solution in .Net Core. In my case I have a base DbContext where I interpret a custom DataAnnotation in order to tell EF to ignore certain properties on my model classes (the functionality I wanted to test).

I could not simply use `NotMapped` because it caused OData to not be able to see `NotMapped` properties when specified in the `$select`, so I needed an alternative way to tell EF to ignore, but not impact OData.

In my case I also created a `TestDbContext` which inherited from my standard test `ModelDbContext` class (which in turn inherits from my library `DbContextBase` class which does the EF Ignore work), but I simply set a property to the provided `ModelBuilder` so that I could interrogate it during my tests.

```
    public class TestDbContext : ModelDbContext
    {
      public ModelBuilder ModelBuilder { get; private set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        this.ModelBuilder = modelBuilder;
      }
    }
```

Then I could test it using the following code:

Note: I had to use reflection to extract the EF internal classes required to determine if indeed the field was set to Ignored. This is normally bad practice, but I could not figure out another way of determining whether EF was ignoring these properties.

```
    [Fact]
    public void OnModelCreatingTest()
    {
      // Arrange
      DbContextOptionsBuilder<ModelDbContext> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ModelDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
      var context = new TestDbContext(builder.Options);

      // Act
      // hit the entities to force the model to build
      var testEntity = context.ExampleEntities.FirstOrDefault();
      // use reflection to dig into EF internals
      var builderProperty = typeof(EntityTypeBuilder).GetProperty(
          "Builder",
          System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

      // Assert
      // validate that the extra ExampleEntity fields are ignored in EF (based on their data annotation)
      context.ModelBuilder.Entity(
        typeof(ExampleEntity),
        b =>
        {
          InternalEntityTypeBuilder baseBuilder = (InternalEntityTypeBuilder)builderProperty.GetValue(b);
          Assert.True(baseBuilder.IsIgnored("Property1", ConfigurationSource.Convention));
          Assert.True(baseBuilder.IsIgnored("Property2", ConfigurationSource.Convention));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this! I was getting 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext', but was able to resolve by overriding the OnConfiguring method in the TestDbContext and calling `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);`

Answer (score 3):

You could create a stub for you DbContext that explicit call `OnModelCreating` and check the state of the `DbModelBuilder`

```
public class TestableMyDbContext : MyDbContext
{
  public void TestModelCreation(DbModelBuilder model)
  {
    OnModelCreating(model);
    // check your model an throw an exception if invalid
  }
}
```

And in the TestMethod you catch the exception

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_Initialize_Context()
{
  try
  {
    var context = new TestableMyDbContext();
    context.TestModelCreation(new DbModelBuilder());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on vappolinario's answer, I used a `Mock<DbModelBuilder>` and passed that into the `TestableDbContext`, and then verified that the mock was called correctly.

*I am using Moq and xUnit in my example*

```
[Fact]
public void MyContext_HasCorrectDefaultSchema()
{
   var mockModel = new Mock<DbModelBuilder>();
   var context = new TestableMyContext();

   context.TestOnModelCreation(mockModel.Object);

   mockModel.Verify(m => m.HasDefaultSchema("public"), Times.Once());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to mention that in EF Core 2.2 you can simply do this:

```
public class MyDbContextTests
{
    [Test]
    public void OnModelCreating_CreateAllModels_AllModelsCreated()
    {
        var context = new MyDbContext();

        Assert.That(() => context.Model, Throws.Nothing);
    }
}
```

Here, `MyDbContext` inherits `DbContext`. This test will call both the protected `OnConfiguring` followed by `OnModelCreating` methods within the `MyDbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the stub technique to work, but this did:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_Initialize_Context()
{
    try
    {
        var context = new MyDbContextContext("blah");
        context.Database.Initialize(false);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
    }
}
```